# URL blocked by robots.txt

Tags: xml, url, sitemap, robots.txt

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong. I am new to coding on websites but have been researching about sitemaps and their links to robots.txt files, as google webmaster will not add my sitemaps because of apparently my robots.txt is blocking them. This is my robots.txt file:

[robots.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHfJP.jpg)

I am only starting out so I will add more coding as time progresses but for now can someone with a better understanding than me, tell me whats wrong with this and that is not my actual website. Thank you.

Comment: Please cut'n' paste the file and put that into the post

Answer (score 0):

Your image link is broken so I am unable to view it. I don't know how you wrote the code but I am providing the correct syntax below:

User-agent: *
Allow: /

The above code will grant the permission for all search engine bots to crawl your complete website. If you want to add sitemap path in robots.txt, use below syntax:
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://yoursitename.com/sitemap.xml

Let me know if I can be of more help to you.